# Proper mySQL Statement for Searching Availability Dates

Tags: mysql

I realize this question has been asked in various forms but I am struggling with its implementation into my application.

Here are my table setup:

```
home: home_id, booking_id, name, address, location, etc
booking: booking_id, fromdate, todate
```

I am trying to build a search that will return the homes availability.  So if home "A" is not booked from "4/4/2011 - 4/10/2011"  then it will return home "A" as the result.

Thanks for your help.

Ok, so based on what you guys have said I have made the adjustment to my tables to normalize them and then used the following query within my PHP:

SELECT home.home_id, home.name, home.address
FROM home 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT home_id
           FROM booking
           WHERE fromdate BETWEEN '2011-04-06' AND '2011-04-07'
           OR todate BETWEEN '2011-04-06' AND '2011-04-07') booking
ON home.home_id = booking.home_id
WHERE booking.home_id IS NULL

However, when I have an entry in my booking table that is "booking_id = 1", "home_id = 1", "from_date = 2011-03-31", "to_date = 2011-04-10" using the above example returns this row which I do not want.  I am going to try the greater than values to see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT H.home_id, H.name, H.address, H.location
FROM Home H
LEFT JOIN (SELECT booking_id
           FROM booking
           WHERE @fromdate BETWEEN fromdate AND todate
           OR @todate BETWEEN fromdate AND todate) B
ON H.booking_id = B.booking_id
WHERE B.booking_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to work unless you start with a normalized database - your current schema makes no sense - presumably a home can have multiple bookings - yet you appear to have booking_id as a foreign key in the home table referencing bookings - this should be the other way around (booking should reference home_id).

Using the correct schema:

```
SELECT home.*
FROM home h
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM booking b
   WHERE b.end_date>$start_time
   AND b.start_date<$end_time
   AND b.home_id=h.home_id
);
```

or

```
SELECT home.*
FROM home h 
LEFT JOIN booking b
ON (b.home_id=h.home_id
   AND b.end_date>$start_time
   AND b.start_date<$end_time
)
WHERE b.home_id IS NULL;
```

With an index on booking (start_time, end_time, home_id) it should be reasonably efficient.